# Java using generic types with interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface, user-defined

I'm building a Java library, and I want the user to be able to define his own versions of some built-in classes, implementing interfaces.

Now I got the following classes, where Evaluator is the built-in main routine that does some processing on Values (built-in or user-defined classes, implementing the Value interface)

The Evaluator is constructed with a Processor (built-in or user-defined class, implementing the Processor interface), and the Processor does the work on the Values.

Thus now I want to work with the Value interface in the Evaluator class and the Processor interface, while working with UserValues in the UserProcessor class, but I don't seem to get this right

Value interface:

```
 public interface Value {
     public Value valueOf(String s)
}
```

User defined Value class which is processed by the program

```
public class UserValue implements Value { … }
public class DefaultValue implements Value { … }
```

Interface defining what actions on objects of Value there will be

```
public interface Processor<T extends Value> {
    public T process(T value);
}
```

Class which does something with some objects of the user-defined Value class.
UserProcessor MUST use UserValue

```
public class UserProcessor implements Processor<UserValue>
public class DefaultProcessor implements Processor<DefaultValue>
```

Class containing the main routine:

```
public class Evaluator {
    private Processor<Value> processor;
    public Evaluator() {
        setProcessor(new DefaultProcessor());
    }
    public void setProcessor(Processor<Value> processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }
    public Value evaluate(String s) {
        Value val = processor.ValueOf(s);
        return processor.process(val);
    }
}
```

`setProcessor(new DefaultProcessor())` gives an error:

```
The method setProcessor(Processor<Value>) in the type Evaluator is not applicable for the arguments (DefaultProcessor)
```

So to clarify the routine: the Evaluator is constructed, optionally the user sets a custom Processor and Value class, and the evaluator tries to parse a String.

Comment: What is this `JavaProcessor` the compiler is complaining about?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change that to DefaultProcessor (changed the names from my original code to make it more clear)